# Prevent non-US Letters in Form Submit (java)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a java JSP/servlet application in a Tomcat, and fronted by an Apache.

The server side checks to make sure only letters in ranges [A..Z][a..z], digits, and punctuation symbols are accepted.

However, when a, for example, chinese character is entered, the value in the server-side looks something like '&#5960".

Hence, as far as the server-side is concerned, these are valid punctuation symbols and digits.

Any pointers that can help? Driving me insane after a 10 coding marathon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) in Java.

```
unescapeHtml(String str)
```

does the following:

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing
>   the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the text using a unicode encoding like UTF-8.

First make sure your server is handling requests with UTF-8 encoding. Where you set or configure that will depend on how you're implementing your JSPs/Servlets, but see: [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)